Where in his works does Maimonides address how to understand אלו ואלו דברי אלקים חיים and the nature of makhloket more broadly (besides intro to PhM)?
Given what Maimonides says in his introduction to his Commentary on the Mishnah (Perush ha-Mishnayot) it seems like he is not a pluralist when it comes to truth in a makhloket (halakhic debate). He states:

אבל מה שאמרו משרבו תלמידי שמאי והלל שלא שמשו כל צרכם רבתה מחלוקת
בישראל ענין זה מבואר שכל ב' אנשים בהיותם שוים בשכל ובעיון ובידיעת
העיקרים שיוציאו מהם הסברות לא תפול ביניהם מחלוקת בסברתם בשום פנים ואם
נפלה תהיה מעוטא. כמו שלא נמצא שנחלקו שמאי והלל אלא בהלכות יחידות.
Rather, the matter of that which they said, "From when the students of
Shammai and Hillel – who did not serve all that was required of them –
multiplied, disagreement grew in Israel," is evident; in that when two
people are of equal intellect and investigation and knowledge of the
fundamentals from which reasonings extrapolate, no disagreement will
occur in their reasonings in any way. And if it does occur, it will be
minimal; as it is only found that Shammai and Hillel disagreed about
isolated laws.

Two people carrying out the correct deductions should reach the same conclusions about the law. Prima facie, the Gemara in Eiruvin 14b (and Ritva ad. loc.) suggests that multiple opinions can be correct, seemingly contrary to Maimonides' picture.
The Ritva writes:

אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים. שאלו רבני צרפת ז"ל היאך אפשר שיהו שניהם דברי
אלהים חיים וזה אוסר וזה מתיר, ותירצו כי כשעלה משה למרום לקבל תורה הראו
לו על כל דבר ודבר מ"ט פנים לאיסור ומ"ט פנים להיתר, ושאל להקב"ה על זה,
ואמר שיהא זה מסור לחכמי ישראל שבכל דור ודור ויהיה הכרעה כמותם, ונכון
הוא לפי הדרש ובדרך האמת יש טעם וסוד בדבר.
"These and those are the words of the Living God" The French rabbis
asked him, "how is it possible that both these and those are the words
of the Living God, this one permits and this one forbids?" And he
answered that when Moshe ascended to receive the Torah, it was
shown to him that every matter was subject to forty-nine
lenient and forty-nine stringent approaches. And he asked the Holy One Blessed Be He about
this, and He responded that it was transmitted to the scholars of Israel of each generation to decide for themselves [the normative halakhah]. And this is correct according to exegetical
interpretation and on the "path of truth" there is a rationale and
esoteric secret in the matter.

Where in his writings does Maimonides address how to understand this?

"Given what he says in his introduction to PhM (perush hamishnayot)" It's a fairly robust intro... what specifically are you trying to claim there contradicts the idea of אלו ואלו? "the GM in Eiruvin suggests" What does GM stand for? Also, how are you understanding אלו ואלו such that you are perceiving a conflict?

@Deuteronomy, It seems like in the introduction the suggestion is that there are correct and incorrect answers to halakhic questions. Some version of the law of excluded middle, if you prefer. GM stands for gemara. The GM in Eiruvin seems to suggest that two mutually exclusive answers are correct (both the pure and impure verdicts are somehow true). In short, PhM seems to suggest law of excluded middle and the GM in Eiruvin seems to contradict that.

You are re-stating, without pointing to the specific language used that you find challenging. Also, please cite where in the Gemara 'Erubhin you find suggestion for your interpretation (specific language, daf, a particular perush, etc.).

Sorry it wasn't clear. The GM in Eruvin is 13b. I think the simple reading of the GM there is that somehow both opinions are true but we must decide what to do practically and follow one. See the comments of the Ritva which seems to support this. Here is the section from intro to PhM I am referring to:
אבל מה שאמרו משרבו תלמידי שמאי והלל שלא שמשו כל צרכם רבתה מחלוקת בישראל ענין זה מבואר שכל ב' אנשים בהיותם שוים בשכל ובעיון ובידיעת העיקרים שיוציאו מהם הסברות לא תפול ביניהם מחלוקת בסברתם בשום פנים ואם נפלה תהיה מעוטא. כמו שלא נמצא שנחלקו שמאי והלל אלא בהלכות יחידות.

Thank you, please edit your clarifications into the question. Presenting your questions in a well-researched, thought out manner is strongly encouraged here :)

Ok. I can add them to the question. I believe all these things are very basic though if you have ever studied any of these sources …

Apologies if that assumption was presumptuous or made my question unclear.

and some may argue that the answer to this question is also very basic if you've studied the sources ;) Either way, presenting the question without ambiguity and in a manner that anyone could immediately understand the question and its basis is strongly encouraged. Thanks for trying to clarify and provide context for all.
